# spark higher order function transform output struct

Tags: apache-spark, struct, apache-spark-sql, higher-order-functions, complextype

How can I `transform` an array of structs to again a struct using spark higher order functions?

The dataset:

```
case class Foo(thing1:String, thing2:String, thing3:String)
case class Baz(foo:Foo, other:String)
case class Bar(id:Int, bazes:Seq[Baz])
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(Bar(1, Seq(Baz(Foo("first", "second", "third"), "other"), Baz(Foo("1", "2", "3"), "else")))).toDF
df.printSchema
df.show(false)
```

I want to concatenate all `thing1, thign2, thing3` but keep the `other` property for each `bar`.

A simple:

```
scala> df.withColumn("cleaned", expr("transform(bazes, x -> x)")).printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- bazes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- foo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- thing1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- thing2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- thing3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- other: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cleaned: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- foo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- thing1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- thing2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- thing3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- other: string (nullable = true)
```

Will only copy the thing over.

The desired concatentate operation:

```
 df.withColumn("cleaned", expr("transform(bazes, x -> concat(x.foo.thing1, '::', x.foo.thing2, '::', x.foo.thing3))")).printSchema
```

will, unfortunately, remove all the values form the `other` column:

```
 +---+----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|id |bazes                                               |cleaned                        |
+---+----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|1  |[[[first, second, third], other], [[1, 2, 3], else]]|[first::second::third, 1::2::3]|
+---+----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

How can these be retained?
Trying to keep the tuples:

```
df.withColumn("cleaned", expr("transform(bazes, x -> (concat(x.foo.thing1, '::', x.foo.thing2, '::', x.foo.thing3), x.other))")).printSchema
```

fails with:

```
.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'named_struct('col1', concat(namedlambdavariable().`foo`.`thing1`, '::', namedlambdavariable().`foo`.`thing2`, '::', namedlambdavariable().`foo`.`thing3`), NamePlaceholder(), namedlambdavariable().`other`)' due to data type mismatch: Only foldable string expressions are allowed to appear at odd position, got: NamePlaceholder; line 1 pos 22;
```

### edit

The desired output:

- a new column with contents:

  [[first::second::third, other], [1::2::3,else]

which retain the column `other`

Comment: can you please add expected output.it is not directly accessibly bcoz foo and other are sharing same hierarchy. so please add your desired output. so I could able to add the answer for your question.

Comment: is it clearer now?

Comment: yes I  have added answer please check and accept

Comment: ou concat other, but I would like to keep it as a separate column inside the outputted struct.

Comment: Ok got your point

Comment: I have just updated answer as per your requirement.

Comment: not sure if that helps but `df.withColumn("cleaned", expr("transform(bazes, x -> array(concat(x.foo.thing1, '::', x.foo.thing2, '::', x.foo.thing3), x.other))"))
` works. However it gives an array of arrays not a struct. I didn't see a way to get the required struct

Comment: @MaheshGupta I posted a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59018359/how-to-return-a-case-class-when-using-spark-high-order-functions) in which I try to return a case class instead of a struct. Do you have any ideas if that is possible?

Comment: Question not directly related to this post, can I use an if condition with a higher order function. I've got an iterative algo that stops when the values for the adjustment factors and the index do not change anymore. atm this implemented in plain pyspark and takes is very slow @GeorgHeiler

Comment: Potentially a collect list and udf is faster. If it is a graph look at cugraph instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In this way, you can achieve your desired output. you cannot directly access other value bcoz foo and other are sharing the same hierarchy. so you need to access other separately.

```
scala>  df.withColumn("cleaned", expr("transform(bazes, x -> struct(concat(x.foo.thing1, '::', x.foo.thing2, '::', x.foo.thing3),cast(x.other as string)))")).show(false)
+---+----------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|id |bazes                                               |cleaned                                         |
+---+----------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

> printSchema

```
scala>  df.withColumn("cleaned", expr("transform(bazes, x -> struct(concat(x.foo.thing1, '::', x.foo.thing2, '::', x.foo.thing3),cast(x.other as string)))")).printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- bazes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- foo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- thing1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- thing2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- thing3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- other: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cleaned: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
```

let me know if you have further any question related to the same.

Comment: please see the updated desired output. You concat `other`, but I would like to keep it as a separate column inside the outputted struct.

Comment: Interesting. can you explain why: `df.withColumn("cleaned", expr("transform(bazes, x -> struct(concat(x.foo.thing1, '::', x.foo.thing2, '::', x.foo.thing3),x.other))")).show(false)` will not work? i.e. you still seem to pull the other column into the concat operation.

Comment: What I mean is: the struct still only holds a single column. I want the struct to hold two separate columns.

Comment: In higher-order function, it is not able to identify x.other column for creating new value for struct that why I used x.other inside concat function.

Comment: Interesting is that even a field is `string` you still need to explicitly cast it to `string` to work. Otherwise it just throws an exception