# How to return a case class when using Spark High Order Functions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to use Spark [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) function in order to transform the items of an array from type ClassA into ClassB as shown below:

```scala
case class ClassA(a: String, b: String, c: String)
case class ClassB(a: String, b: String)

val a1 = ClassA("a1", "b1", "c1")
val a2 = ClassA("a2", "b2", "c2")

val df = Seq(
(Seq(a1, a2))
).toDF("ClassA")

df.withColumn("ClassB", expr("transform(ClassA, c -> ClassB(c.a, c.b))")).show(false)
```

Although the above code fails with the message:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'ClassB'.
>   This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a
>   permanent function registered in the database 'default'.

The only way to make this work was through `struct` as shown next:

```
df.withColumn("ClassB", expr("transform(ClassA, c -> struct(c.a as string, c.b as string))")).show(false)

// +----------------------------+--------------------+
// |ClassA                      |ClassB              |
// +----------------------------+--------------------+
// |[[a1, b1, c1], [a2, b2, c2]]|[[a1, b1], [a2, b2]]|
// +----------------------------+--------------------+
```

So the question is if there is any way to return a case class instead of a struct when using `transform`?

Comment: I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57943560/spark-higher-order-function-transform-output-struct) which is partially related although not solving the case class issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `transform` expression is relational and doesn't know anything about case classes `ClassA` and `ClassB`.
The only way you have AFAIK would be to register an UDF so you can use your structure (or inject functions) but you would also have to deal with a "`Row`" encoded value instead of ClassA (SparkSQL is all about encoding :) ) like so :

```
sparkSession.udf.register("toB", (a: Row) => ClassB(a.getAs[String]("a"), a.getAs[String]("b")))

df.withColumn("ClassB", expr("transform(ClassA, c -> toB(c))")).show(false)
```

Side note: Naming your column "ClassA" might be confusing since transform is reading the column, not the type.

Comment: I think you got exactly the point, I was wondering if there is any way to use/write a generic function which can handle the mapping that you implemented above for custom types (case class)